# Visual Studio SDL2.dll The code execution cannot proceed because SDL2.dll was not found

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to make a window with c++ and SDL, But when I launch my code, it says "The code execution cannot proceed because SDL2.dll was not found." And yes, it is confusing because I have SDL2.dll in my source files. Do anyone know how to fix it.?

Code:

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 255);

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        SDL_Delay(3000);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the DLL in relation to your executable. Visual Studio does not put your executable in the same directory as your source files.

Comment: The search for the DLL will be in the working directory and the system path. It is unlikely that the system will look in the same folder as the code. Find the working directory and move the DLL there or, usually better, properly install the SDL library and add it to the system path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may either manually copypaste it to your final build folder, or add this file to a project and specify its build action as Copy to Output (it used to work for me).

I think there may be option to set up a working directory in a project settings as well.

Comment: Final build folder might not be the working directory either. For example, Visual Studio uses the project's root directory as the working directory.